# entrypoint! function is conflicting with the solana program entrypoint! function

Tags: anchor, solana-program, entrypoint

I create a Solana native program that is being compiled successfully but then I import that program in a rust crate and use that crate in other program in `anchor` program but I'm getting this error

```
 /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev-ice/bitoku/bitoku-user-sample/target/debug/deps/libbitoku_sdk_agent_native-82a6d751ee4c4264.rlib(bitoku_sdk_agent_native-82a6d751ee4c4264.bitoku_sdk_agent_native.d62308ee-cgu.15.rcgu.o): in function `entrypoint':
          /home/dev-ice/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/solana-program-1.14.13/src/entrypoint.rs:126: multiple definition of `entrypoint'; /home/dev-ice/bitoku/bitoku-user-sample/target/debug/deps/sample_program.1iglnqtogkpe73be.rcgu.o:/home/dev-ice/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/solana-program-1.14.13/src/entrypoint.rs:126: first defined here
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

so the `entrypoint` of the `solana program` is conflicting with the `entrypoint` of my program. But that program is being comipiled and run successfully!

here's cargo.toml for the native porgram

```
[package]
name = "bitoku-sdk-agent-native"
version = "0.1.8"
edition = "2021"
description = "bitoku-sdk-agnet program"
license = "MIT"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[features]
no-entrypoint = []

[dependencies]
solana-program = {version="1.14.13", features =["no-entrypoint"] }
borsh = "0.9"
thiserror = "1.0.20"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
```

cargo.toml for the intermediate crate

```
[package]
name = "bitoku-sdk"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
solana-program = "1.13.5"
bitoku-sdk-agent-native = {version = "0.1.9", features=["no-entrypoint"]}
```

and `cargo.toml` for the anchor program that is throwing the error

```
[package]
name = "sample-program"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "sample_program"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.26.0"
bitoku-sdk =    {path = "../../../bitoku-sdk",version="0.1.0"}
```

Update :
I tried this in a fresh anchor program and I got this, which I was getting previously as well

```
the `#[global_allocator]` in this crate conflicts with global allocator in: bitoku_sdk_agent_native

error: could not compile `hello` due to previous error
```

but there is no global allocator like from `std::alloc`

this is the program that is throwing this error

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use bitoku_sdk::*;

// const MAX_ENTRY_LEN: usize = 1_000_000;

declare_id!("EjLMs3HBGWxEpzF7yGQTuDwjiNcagYTt4D6pWt7oPqM4");

#[program]
pub mod sample_program {
    use super::*;

    //This function will register a diary client.
    pub fn init_diary(ctx: Context<InitDiary>) -> Result<()> {
        //sdk agent logic

        let accounts = &CpiAccounts {
            fee_payer: ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info(),
            bookkeeper: ctx.accounts.bookkeeper.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            bitoku_agent_program_id: ctx.accounts.agent.to_account_info(),
            request: ctx.accounts.request.to_account_info(),
            sys_var_program: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        };

        let my_id = reg_client(accounts);

        //actual program logic
        ctx.accounts.diary.owner = *ctx.accounts.owner.key;
        ctx.accounts.diary.last_update = ctx.accounts.clock.unix_timestamp;
        ctx.accounts.diary.bitoku_client_id = my_id;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn add_entry(ctx: Context<AddEntry>, diary_content: String) -> Result<()> {
        //sdk logic
        let accounts = &CpiAccounts {
            fee_payer: ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info(),
            bookkeeper: ctx.accounts.bookkeeper.to_account_info(),
            request: ctx.accounts.request.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            sys_var_program: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
            bitoku_agent_program_id: ctx.accounts.agent.to_account_info(),
        };

        // Actual program logic

        let mut arr: [u8; 1024] = [0; 1024];
        let bytes = diary_content.as_bytes();
        arr[..bytes.len()].copy_from_slice(bytes);

        let file_name = "diary".to_string();

        write_file(&accounts, &file_name, arr, 1);

        ctx.accounts.diary.last_update = ctx.accounts.clock.unix_timestamp;
        ctx.accounts.diary.num_entries += 1;

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitDiary<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    owner: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer= owner,
        space= 8+32+1+8+4,
        seeds= ["diary".as_ref(), owner.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    diary: Account<'info, DiaryDescriptor>,

    ///CHECK
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds =["book_keeper".as_bytes()],
        seeds::program=agent,
        bump
     )]
    bookkeeper: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    ///CHECK
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            "request".as_bytes(),
            owner.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        seeds::program=agent,
        bump
    )]
    request: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    ///CHECK
    agent: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    clock: Sysvar<'info, Clock>,

    system_program: Program<'info, System>,

    rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct AddEntry<'info> {
    owner: Signer<'info>,

    ///CHECK
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds =["book_keeper".as_bytes()],
        seeds::program=agent,
        bump
     )]
    bookkeeper: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    ///CHECK
    agent: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = ["diary".as_bytes(),owner.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    diary: Account<'info, DiaryDescriptor>,

    ///CHECK
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            "request".as_bytes(),
            owner.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        seeds::program=agent,
        bump
    )]
    request: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    clock: Sysvar<'info, Clock>,

    system_program: Program<'info, System>,

    rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

#[account]
pub struct DiaryDescriptor {
    owner: Pubkey,
    bitoku_client_id: u8,
    last_update: i64,
    num_entries: u32,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I had to add this line `#[cfg(not(feature = "no-entrypoint"))]` in the `lib.rs` of the `native-program`

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to add the `no-entrypoint` feature to your imported crate.

`bitoku-sdk = {path = "../../../bitoku-sdk", features = ["no-entrypoint"]}`

Comment: already done that, no difference